# Calculating $a_0$ in Fourier Series

Tags: integration, fourier-series

[image]

I am using this YouTube video to learn Fourier Series. The question can be clearly seen in the picture. The instructor calculates $a_0$ as the area under the triangle which is fine. Nothing wrong with it, I get it.

However, I was trying to calculate is as a sum of integration as:
$$
a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}[\int_{-\pi}^{0}f(x)dx + \int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx]
$$

However, I am unable to get the right answer. I get my answer as $\frac{1}{4}$

**Can someone please tell me what is going wrong?**

Comment: You get $a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}[\int_{-\pi}^0 0\,dx + \int_0^\pi x\,dx]$ by inserting the definition of $f$. $\int_0^a x\,dx = \frac{a^2}{2}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you expand on it please ? I have calculated $a_0$ before but this one seems to be slightly confusing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first integral is zero (which follows from the definition of $f$). The second integral is $x^2/2$ (again using the definition of $f$) evaluated at $\pi$, so $\ldots$

Comment: That solves it for me :) The confusion arose because most of the sums that I did had values of $f(x)$ as constants. 4, 3, 5, etc. So, I never integrated anything. I just plugged it in. So, now I know that if it $f(x)$ for an interval is a variable, you need to integrate :)

Comment: Yes. Simply use the definition of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

$$a_0 = 0 + \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{\pi} dx \, x  = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac12 \pi^2 = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Why did you not substitute $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for first term of the sum?? I mean, that is what the piecewise defn. says. When x = $-\pi$, you get $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @LittleChild: the first term of what sum?  You mean above?  $f(x)=0$ when $x \in [-\pi,0]$.

Comment: yes. Thats what I meant.

Comment: @LittleChild: because we are integrating.  Let's say you are right - the integral over this point of discontinuity is exactly zero because that point has measure zero.